# org-html-link-org-files-as-html for LaTeX export?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am using org-mode to write my labbook. Each experiment is an org-file that is exported to PDF when finished. Currently, I am linking to previous experiments by using the resulting PDF. Is it possible to link to org-files instead and have org-mode convert the link to PDF once exported?

This would make it easier to jump from experiment to experiment inside Emacs and from PDF to PDF once exported.

I am aware that this is done for HTML export. How do I set this up for LaTeX export?

Comment: Can you share one of your books (google drive?) if you don't mind? I'm a org user but I have not be able to use it for anything other than organizing / planning / scheduling. I would like to see how you are doing your lab book.

Comment: I think it would be best to apply org export filters. http://orgmode.org/org.html#Advanced-configuration

Comment: @Prasanna I am using the setup by the Kitchin lab - [Scimax](https://github.com/jkitchin/scimax) with which I created a projectile project for each project I am working in. Inside each project I create a folder for each experiment (I give each experiment a number). Then inside that folder I have the .org file for the experiment in which I write down my purpose for the experiment, the procedure (which are also TODO tasks that are scheduled) and my data analysis (with R/ESS) and results from the experiment.

The org-file is then exported via latex to PDF.

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm thank you for the suggestion, I will give it a look.

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm at the end I did the following:


(defun my-latex-filter-macro (text backend info)

  "Replace .org with .pdf"

  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)

    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\.org" ".pdf" text)))



(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-link-functions

             'my-latex-filter-macro)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did the following:

```
(defun my-latex-filter-macro (text backend info)

  "Replace .org with .pdf"

  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'latex)

    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\.org" ".pdf" text)))



(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-link-functions

             'my-latex-filter-macro)
```